# Difference tool QGIS

Tags: qgis, r, vector

I am trying to use difference tool in QGIS to get a mask out the ice coverage from a base vector map. The number of features in ice coverage is around 2000 while my base map has 237 features. I am using

I tried using difference tool to do it but it got unresponsive and stuck at 79%.

I also tried `gdifference` function to do it in R. But, it doesn't create `spatialpolygondataframe` but a `spatialpolygon` when I tried a difference of subset of my vector layer.

I am now trying to do it using a batch process in QGIS differencing 200 features at once. However, it seems to be taking a very long time. The time taken increases with every consequent batch process. Considering that I have to further mask out other layers also, it will probably take a very long time like this.
Is there any other (faster) way to do this?